# consuming asmx webservice in xamarin forms

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms, asmx

I am working on a login page in Xamarin forms and I need to consume an asmx webservice in order to connect to the sql server. I used this example: https://github.com/fabiosilvalima/FSL.ConsummingAsmxServicesInXamarinForms, and tried to apply the same steps for my app. but I got an error.

here's my code:
ILogin.cs:

```
namespace App33.Models
{
    public interface ILogin
    {
         string Error { get; set; }
         bool ValidUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ILoginSoapService.cs

```
  public interface ILoginSoapService
    {
        Task<List<ILogin>> Login(string namee, string passs);
    }
```

in App.xaml.cs

```
 private static ILoginSoapService _loginSoapService;

        public static ILoginSoapService LoginSoapService

        {

            get

            {

                if (_loginSoapService == null)

                {

                    _loginSoapService = DependencyService.Get<ILoginSoapService>();

                }



                return _loginSoapService;

            }
```

Main.xaml.cs

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var entr_usrname = this.FindByName<Entry>("username");
            string usrname = entr_usrname.Text;
            var entr_pass = this.FindByName<Entry>("Password");
            string pass = entr_pass.Text;
            var state = await App.LoginSoapService.Login(usrname,pass);
            if (state[0].ValidUser == true)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
            }

        }
```

this is for the portable app. my webservice is added to the web reference as LoginWs. it has the following codes:

Result.cs:

```
public class Result
    {
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public bool ValidUser { get; set; }
    }
```

WebService1.asmx.cs:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public Result Login(string userName, string userPass)
        {
            SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection (new DBConnection().ConnectionString);
            Result result = new Result();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT userName, password FROM users where CONVERT(VARCHAR, username)=@username and CONVERT(VARCHAR, password)=@password");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", userName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", userPass);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                if (conn.State==System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    result.ValidUser = true;
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.ValidUser = false;

                }
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                result.Error = ex.ToString();
                
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

now in App.Android:

Result.cs

```
namespace App33.Droid.LoginWs
{
    public partial class Result : ILogin

    {

    }
}
```

LoginSoapService.cs

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(App33.Droid.LoginSoapService))]
namespace App33.Droid
{
    public sealed class LoginSoapService :ILoginSoapService
    {
        

        LoginWs.WebService1 service;



        public LoginSoapService()

        {

            service = new LoginWs.WebService1()

            {

               // Url = "http://codefinal.com/FSL.ConsummingAsmxServicesInXamarinForms/Customers.asmx" //remote server

                 Url = "http://192.168.0.106/site2/WebService1.asmx" //localserver - mobile does not understand "localhost", just that ip address

            };

        }



        public async Task<List<ILogin>> Login( string namee,string pass)

        {

            return await Task.Run(() =>

            {

                var result = service.Login(namee,pass);

               

                return new List<ILogin>(result);

            });

        }

    }
}
```

the error i'm getting is in this line:return new List(result);. it says: Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'App33.Droid.LoginWs.Result' to 'int'. I can't figure out what the peoblem is. sorry for the long question. any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't use ASMX.  Use a RESTful service.  SOAP is a very outdated technology and will make you miserable.

Comment: @Jason yes I can feel miserable already. but I can't find a suitable tutorial to understand the restful webservice and consume it. could you kindly provide me with one if you have?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/web-service/?tabs=vswin

Comment: @Jason thanks a lot sir