# Trying to Consume an ASMX web services in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

1. I referenced the web service in both my Android and iOS apps.
2. I created the interface IClientSoapServices.cs

   namespace CandidateOrderingApp
   {

   ```
        public interface IClientServices
    {
        int UserKey { get; set; }
        int ClientKey { get; set; }
        int ClientDB { get; set; }
        String ClientName { get; set; }
        String AccountNo { get; set; }
        String ClientBranch { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IClientSoapServices
    {
        Task<List<IClientServices>> CheckWTLoagin(string code = null, string username = null, 
        string password = null);
    }
   ```

   }
3. Then I created a class "ClientSoapService" in in the android project that implemments that my "ICustomerSoapService" interface :

   [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(CandidateOrderingApp.Droid.ClientSoapServices))]
   namespace CandidateOrderingApp.Droid
   {
   public sealed class ClientSoapServices: IClientSoapServices
   {
   CandidateOrderingApp.Droid.za.co.workforce.intranet.Service1 service;

   ```
        public ClientSoapServices()
        {
            service = new CandidateOrderingApp.Droid.za.co.workforce.intranet.Service1();
            {
                service.Url = "https://intranet.workforce.co.za/WFService//WF_Service.asmx";
            };
        }

        public async Task<List<IClientServices>> CheckWTLoagin(string code = null, string username = null, string password = null)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var result = service.CheckWTLoagin(code, username, password);
                return new List<IClientServices>(result);
            });
        }
    }
   ```

   }
4. Then, in my App.xaml.cs file, I created a property to be injected (dependency injection) by Xamarin Forms:

   private static IClientSoapServices _clientSoapService;
   public static IClientSoapServices ClientSoapServices
   {
   get
   {
   if (_clientSoapService == null)
   {
   _clientSoapService = DependencyService.Get();
   }

   ```
        return _clientSoapService;
    }
   ```

   }

I am getting an error in my 'ClientSoapServices' class which implements the IClientSoapServices interface

The error I'm getting is:

CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CandidateOrderingApp.Droid.za.co.workforce.intranet.WTClients[]' to 'int'

[snippet of code where I get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slHaG.png)

Here is another post where they have seem to have the same error: [consuming asmx webservice in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938101/consuming-asmx-webservice-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Can you create the List with the default  constructor and do `AddRange`  on that instance method?

Comment: `CheckWTLoagin` returns a `Task`, but you are not awaiting it